# Combine query in the TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to combine the SQL queries and getting the below error.

> The name 'SELECT id,tbprojectnumber, importdatetime FROM [TestDatabase].[landing].[details]' is not a valid identifier.

```
DECLARE @Q1 varchar(5000)
SELECT @Q1 = 'SELECT id,tbprojectnumber, importdatetime'

DECLARE @Q3 varchar(5000)
SELECT @Q3 ='FROM [TestDatabase].[landing].[details]' 


DECLARE @Q5 varchar(5000)
SELECT @Q5  = @Q1 +' '+@Q3
EXEC @Q5
```

when I am running query

```
SELECT id,tbprojectnumber, importdatetime 
FROM [TestDatabase].[landing].[details]
```

I am able to get the results.

Answer (score 3):

`SET` the variable value :

```
SET @Q5  = @Q1 +' '+@Q3

PRINT @Q5 -- Check before execution. 

EXEC sp_executesql @Q5;
```

Use `NVARCHAR()` type while preparing dynamic queries.

For your sample data, you don't need to use two separate variable.

Comment: thanks Yogesh.how can I pass dynamic quires in the merge statement?